# Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class that is not a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I had an activity that contained a fragment and worked perfectly, but when I switched to support fragment from the v4 support library, suddenly began throwing the following error and I can't figure out why.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{RecordActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)                
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class RecordFragment that is not a Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4795)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4795)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at RecordActivity.onCreate(RecordActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**RecordActivity**

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class RecordActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private RecordFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);
        if (getActionBar() != null)
            getActionBar().hide();

        fragment = (RecordFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
        fragment.setReplyText(getIntent().getExtras());
    }
}
```

**RecordFragment**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;    
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewStub;   

public class RecordFragment extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        spf = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(STUDIO_SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_record, container, false);
        ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tsmessage);
        stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.ts_message);
        //more code ...
}
```

**fragment_container.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.android.Fragments.RecordFragment"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have reviewed similar questions but none of the ones I've seen seems to fit to my problem. The activity inherits from FragmentActivity instead of Activity, as suggested in another questions.

I thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Could it be that the package name in your xml is not valid? android:name="com.example.android.RecordFragment" might be the correct value?

Comment: Hi, I've only changed the name of the package to simplify the code

Comment: If you can use support-v7 library, try using `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`. Clearly it is trying to instantiate the fragment as an `android.app.Fragment` type fragment, although I don't see why it should do that.

Answer (score 3):

From the `imports` in `RecordFragment` it looks like `RecordFragment` is extending `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. The inflater is expecting a `android.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `Fragment` in your XML file, sometimes Android confuses `Android.app.Fragment` with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` when inflating.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
Android.app.Fragment import in your MainActivity.java or other java class 
instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment import

sometimes Android confuses
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment with android.app.Fragment

it should work,